# Lazyload post thumbnails

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

My goal is to lazy load thumbnails. As seen in [here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), I need to add `class="lazy"`, placeholder has to be in `src` and lazy loaded image as `data-original`.

This code works perfectly:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    $size = 'attachment-thumbnail-400-300';

    //Get thumbnail source
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail-400-300' );
    $src = $thumb['0'];

    $placeholder = "//placehold.it/400x300/eee/222/&text=+";

    $default_attr = array(
        'src' => $placeholder,
        'data-original' => $src,
        'class' => "lazy $size",
    );
    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-400-300', $default_attr);
}
```

---

This gets source and everything by default:

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-400-300');
```

---

I tried to modify code in many different ways but I got it to work only with this:

```
 $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail-400-300' );
 $src = $thumb['0'];
```

It seems like an extra request I don't need (I need to load A LOT of thumbnails). How to modify my code in order to get `src` directly with `the_post_thumbnail` and assign it as `data-original`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got everything you need, simply build your own `img`-element like this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
   $class = 'lazy attachment-thumbnail-400-300';

   //Get thumbnail source
   $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail-400-300');
   $src = $thumb['0'];

   $placeholder = "//placehold.it/400x300/eee/222/&text=+";

   echo '<img src="'.$placeholder.'" data-original="'.$src.'" class="'.$class.'" />';
}
```

Besides that, your main performance issue might be generating a new placeholder every time you want to display an image. Use a local file for that, it´s only a few bytes in size but saves you that extra request (with all the overhead).

Comment: Is there a big difference if I use thumbnail or build own image? Hmm.. This code is in while loop - placeholder get's requested with every loop? If I use 1x1 px placeholder from local machine, it reuses it with every loop?

Comment: There is no real difference, because `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` simply returns the URL for your 400 x 300 px image. `the_post_thumbnail()` builds additional HTML output around it. I don´t think that´s a problem in any way. And yes, a local file will of course be used again and again. But you can link directly to it and don´t need to connect to a foreign server, generate the image and wait for it... Much faster obviously.

Comment: If you want to test the perf for local vs. placehold.it, check out the [Pref Map Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfmap/hgpnhiajcdppfbogcpfdgcceepgkhdmk?hl=en). It's pretty slick for visualizing load times of image resources. Also, I just wanted to mention that WP 4.4 comes with responsive image support and it's worth taking a look [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/) to see how the markup above might change - should you decide to use responsive images.

Answer (score 0):

> How to modify my code in order to get src directly with the_post_thumbnail and assign it as data-original?

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/).

```
$size = 'attachment-thumbnail-400-300';
$placeholder = 'src="//placehold.it/400x300/eee/222/&text='.urlencode('+').'"';
$pattern = '/src\s*=\s*"(.+?)"/'; 

$thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID , 'thumbnail-400-300'); 

preg_match($pattern, $thumb, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

if ( ! empty($matches) ){

    $src = $matches[0][0];

    $thumb = str_replace( $src, $placeholder, $thumb );

    $thumb = str_replace( 'class="', 'class="' . "lazy $size ", $thumb );

    $data_original = str_replace( 'src="', 'data-original="', $src );

    $thumb = str_replace( ' src="', $data_original . ' src="', $thumb );
}

echo $thumb;
```

Comment: What? no props for using 'the_post_thumbnail' in the solution?